# How to override accessoryView in UITableViewCell to change it's position

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

By default the `accessoryView` on the `UITableViewCell` is positioned to the far right on the cell. I am sub-classing the `UITableViewCell` to try and change this position to move it over more the left, however, it has no effect and it remains to the right. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(100, self.accessoryView.frame.origin.y, self.accessoryView.frame.size.width, self.accessoryView.frame.size.height);
    self.accessoryView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.accessoryView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the default value of `accessoryView` is `nil`. You have to create the view first and assign it to this property in order to customize it.

Comment: You can alternatively edit the the accessoryView image itself to have it leave more white space to the right.

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2876263/294661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Matt's tip the only way I found to do this was to just use my own `UIImageView` and use the image of my choice and then set the `frame` coordinates to what I needed.  This allowed the `accessoryView` to expand.  Apparently this is the only way to manipulate it.

```
UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BV-icon_57x57"];
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:indicatorImage];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20);
        [view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];//without this line the image will just be stretched;
        cell.accessoryView = view;
```

Comment: I am using your code, but its not taking image to left... its still at right... any idea why??

Comment: Hey Fahim, Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code any more, I am on a different job all together or I would look for you. I know this was a royal pain to try and make work.

Comment: @FahimParkar this is definitely a day late and a dollar short but I've been fighting this issue tonight and figure out how to get Flea's solution to work.  You have to use `setContentMode` to left justify the image.  Otherwise it just stretches it.  I've edited the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Implement `layoutSubviews` in your cell subclass, call super as the first thing you do and then modify the frames of the subviews you want to change.

Comment: Wain, I tried that and nothing changed. In fact, I tried changing the background color, adding borders, setting a large height and nothing changes. It's still putting the check mark accessory type to the far right.

Comment: Can you show the code for creating the cell and the layoutSubviews implementation please.

Comment: Technically, because you're using the accessoryType rather than the accessory view we're relying on the framework implementation and it would seem that it isn't using the accessoryView. You should probably create a UIImageView and assign it to the accessoryView.

Comment: Thanks Wain. I just removed the accessory type on the cell and I still can't even get the `accessoryview` to even show up using the code above.

Comment: The custom cell is being created and layoutSubviews called ?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Flea's solution; pushes the image by the given amount instead of a fixed frame:

```
static CGFloat const kRightOffset = 10.0;

cell.accessoryView = ({UIImageView * imgV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
                CGRect frame = imgV.frame;
                frame.size.width = frame.size.width + kRightOffset;
                imgV.frame = frame;
                [imgV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
                imgV; });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to define a custom cell, set Accessory to none, place an imageview that acts on behalf of the accessory view wherever you like, and define a tap gesture handler for the cell (if you want to limit tap gesture to only the image, just add tap gesture only to imageview instead of entire cell). This gives a lot of flexibility, plus we don't have to deal with the annoyances that accessoryview brings (for me at least - i dislike the border on the right of the cell)

In your custom cell setup code:

```swift
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onCellTapped(_:)))
self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc private func onCellTapped(_: Any) {
   //your code here - i added an imageview that changes image on user tap - to indicate selected/deselected
}
```