# How can I move the detail disclosure of a cell from the default location to another location?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I move the detail disclosure of a cell from the default location to another location? In objective-c obliviously.

Comment: obliviously?   I think you mean obviously... either way it is not necessary in the question

Comment: I think the question was well-worded.

Comment: But if I wanted to switch to a view (in a navigation controller) with the click of a button in a cell, how can I do it in prepareForSegue? I can get the index of the cell, and then to do this step by clicking the disclosure, but when I click on my button located in the center of the cell, the indexpath does not exist.

Comment: This is a completly different question. Either edit this one or create a new one.

Comment: Did any answer worked for you? If yes, please accept one in order to remove your question from Unanswered. If not, please give some feedback with new informations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell by overriding UITableViewCell, you haven't done this yet, and poste the method below in your implementation file.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIButton"]) { 

            //Just an example, change the frame by your wish here.
            CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
            newFrame.origin.y -= 15;
            subview.frame = newFrame;
        }

    }

}
```

This approach can be used to edit any default components of TableViewCell, like the disclosure, the delete button when editing, etc. And will not mess with the views that you put inside your cell, because all your manual added views are really inside the `contentView` property.

Works like a charm, but keep in mind that changing the state of a subview that's not accessible outside of the view it's never a good practice (although it will not cause a rejection of your app).

A more elegant solution would be simply use a UIImageView with your custom disclosure and put it inside your cell in the position you want.

---

EDIT:

After the comment below and a downvote I think it's important to point out something:

All the views that you put inside your cell, actually are inside the UITableViewCell property "contentView". So, even though you have buttons inside your cell, they will NOT be listed in the for enumeratino above, because they are actually subViews of the contentView, so the code will still work.

Please, to a little research about UITableViewCellContentView to get more details.

My point here is show that YES, it's possible to move the default disclosure if that's really what you are looking for, but I did tell that's not the better solution.

Comment: so if you provide your own `UIButton`'s within the subviews of your `UITableViewCell`- you think this is still a valid solution? i think not

Comment: All the subviews of your cell are really subViews of the contentView INSIDE the UITableViewCell and will not be listed in this for enumeration... please, do a little research about UITableViewCell and UITableViewCellContentView before downvoting. And I did tell that's not the better solution, my point is showing that YES, it's possible if someone wants this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean and approved way of moving the accessory view, which contains the detail disclosure indicator.  There are some "hacky" ways of moving it, that I would strongly recommend against doing.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6149843/793607) with one person's hack.

Comment: But if I wanted to switch to a view (in a navigation controller) with the click of a button in a cell, how can I do it in prepareForSegue? I can get the index of the cell, and then to do this step by clicking the disclosure, but when I click on my button located in the center of the cell, the indexpath does not exist.