# Vertical center on UITableViewCell accessoryView's element

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I vertically center the content that I have inside a accessoryView from a UITableViewCell? The content is represented by a dynamically added UISwitch that is resized to 50% both width and height using:

```
switchView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

A picture with the problem is:

[image]

Comment: It seems that you cannot change the position (either using frame, centre, translation transformation) of the accessoryView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the position of a `accessoryView`. Please refer to the following question:

[Can a standard accessory view be in a different position within a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876041/can-a-standard-accessory-view-be-in-a-different-position-within-a-uitableviewcel)

It is okay for you to apply transformation such as scale, and rotation to the accessory view. However, you are not able to apply translate transformation to the accessory view. For example,

```
switchView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5),10,10);
```

Only the scale part of the transformation is applied to the `switchView`. Looking through the apple documentation, I also found this following line of note:

> ... The accessory view appears in the right side of the cell.

I don't think apple do want you to customized the location of the accessory view. Based on your question, I also tried changing the centre and the frame of the accessoryView, I do notice that the position of the accessoryView is not moving at all.

In short, If you really want to change the size of the `UISwitch` and move it to the vertical align it in the table view cell, I think you have only one option: You will have to add `UISwitch` as a subview of the cell and then you will have to freedom to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set the appropriate constraint in interface builder: "Vertical Center in Container".

[image: Screenshot]

I would not recommend reducing the size of standard UI elements.

Comment: What constraint do I have to change?

Comment: I updated my answer with a screenshot. It is pretty obvious, though. You should be able to figure out the rest yourself.

Comment: all the UISwitch-es are dynamically added from the code

Comment: Then you are out of luck. You need to subclass your table view cell and put the switch where you want it, rather than using the accessory view.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could do this is by subclassing `UITableViewCell`, and overriding `layoutSubviews` and positioning the `accessoryView` there:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; 
    self.accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(self.accessoryView.frame.origin.x + (self.accessoryView.frame.size.width / 2), (self.frame.size.height - (self.accessoryView.frame.size.height / 2)) / 2, self.accessoryView.frame.size.width, f.size.height);
}
```

I would probably advise you not to resize Apple's prebuilt UI components, especially because [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html) suggest:

> Give tappable controls a hit target of about 44 x 44 points.

The resized switches are smaller.

Nonetheless, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15.5 / Swift 13.4.1

It's a little bit weird when I set a `UIImageView` to `cell.accessoryView`

```swift
let iconView = UIImageView(image: .sfSymbol(of: "lock.fill", size: 17, weight: .semibold))
iconView.bounds = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32)
iconView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
iconView.debugBorder() // Show 1pt border
self.accessoryView = iconView
```

[image]

But when I use an `UIView` as image view's **container**, add **top/bottom/leading/trailing** auto layout, then set container to `cell.accessoryView`, the image is vertically centered in cell:

```swift
let imageContainerView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
let imageView = UIImageView(image: .sfSymbol(of: "lock.fill", size: 17, weight: .semibold))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.debugBorder() // Show 1pt border
imageView.labr.box(imageContainerView, padding: 0).done() // Auto Layout: fill container
self.accessoryView = imageContainerView
```

[image]