# How to add left and right margin for the table cell section?

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS, I have an grouped table view, one section one row as below. How can I set the left and right margin for the cell?

Here is the code I set for the border...

```
[cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.60 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:5];
```

[image: What I have now...]

Expected result: 
[image]

Comment: self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

**Step -1**

create the one Common `UIView` named as `BackgroundView` .and set subview to `cell.contentView`

**Step -2**

set the frame on `BackgroundView` whatever you need. based on contentview width

**Step -3**

add the `Label`, `Date`, `Image` to subview of `BackgroundView`.

**Step -4**

then set the layer for `BackgroundView`, final answer you will get

```
[cell.BackgroundView setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.60 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
[cell.BackgroundView setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[cell.BackgroundView setCornerRadius:5];
```

Comment: Thanks for the steps, I have a question: actually I need content view and accessory view to be inside a same border. If set the border to the background view, is it also include the accessory view?

Comment: @yun -- in your question is good, you can add like create one imageview add the image for functions, else see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876041/can-a-standard-accessory-view-be-in-a-different-position-within-a-uitableviewcel

Comment: Good idea! I just use an arrow image to replace accessory view

Answer (score 4):

The best programming practise for this is subclassing your UITableViewCell and override its ***setFrame*** method.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += 10;
    frame.size.width -= 20;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Also, you can set the corner radius and colour of the cell in ***drawRect*** method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    // border radius
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

    // border
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.60 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
}
```

One more thing, if you just want to make the cell a little more attractive, add this method too in the ***drawRect***:

```
[self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[self.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```