# UITableViewCell accessoryView removing right margin

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

It seems when adding creating a custom `accessoryView` on `UITableViewCell`, iOS adds a default right margin of 15px on iPhone and 20px on iPad. We are trying to put a `UIButton` in the accessory view so this margin is not wanted. Here's a really simple example where the orange square is an accessory view with unwanted right margin:

[image: Screenshot]

I would really prefer to not override `layoutSubviews` and move the `accessoryView` frame. Is there any other way to remove this default margin? Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any soluion?

Comment: The only way I've discovered is custom it in layoutSubviews: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42835490/465916